# @Bean method with null parameter

Tags: java, spring

In My usecase sometimes I do have bean `MyNullable` and sometimes not, what is OK. The problem is when I want to create bean that uses this class (but no always; it will accept `null`).

in code below if I will not provide bean of class `MyNullable` I will have error (no finding dependency). Can I somehow annotate this parameter with smthing like `required = false` link in `@Autowired`?

```
@Bean
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public SynchronousRpcProxy myBean(MyObj1 notNull1, MyObj2 notNull2, MyNullable canBeNull) {
    assert notNull1 != null;
    assert notNull2 != null;
    // assert canBeNull!= null; // this is not true because canBeNull can be null
    return new SmthFromExternalLib(notNull1, notNull2, canBeNull); // do staff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use `Optional` for this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public SynchronousRpcProxy myBean(MyObj1 notNull1, MyObj2 notNull2,
                                  Optional<MyNullable> canBeNull) {
    return new SmthFromExternalLib(notNull1, notNull2, canBeNull.orElse(null));
}
```

When you do this and there is no `MyNullable` bean, the `Optional` will be empty, so that `canBeNull.orElse(null)` returns `null`.

If you are not using Java 8, you can create a factory bean that has `MyNullable` as an optional dependency:

```
@Component
public class SynchronousRpcProxyFactory
                 implements FactoryBean<SynchronousRpcProxy> {

    @Autowired
    private MyObj1 notNull1;

    @Autowired
    private MyObj1 notNull2;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MyNullable canBeNull;

    @Override
    public SynchronousRpcProxy getObject() throws Exception {
        return new SynchronousRpcProxy(notNull1, notNull2, canBeNull);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SynchronousRpcProxy.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, Java 7 on board.

Comment: shouldn't ```isSingleton``` be false? In my example scope is prototype.

Comment: @MAGx2 Yes, obviously, if you don't want your `SynchronousRpcProxy` to be a singleton. I changed it in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use field in configuration class instead of injecting to factory method

```
@Autowired(required=false)
MyNullable canBeNull;
```